# pause main program to wait for dll response

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll

My application (winform) has to access devices on serial ports. All the communication stuff is put in a dll which handles all the serial port communication an has to return the response of the serial device to the main application.
How can I make the main application to wait for the response of the dll to continue with the received data?

Comment: An event-driven approach is generally much better than waiting.  Waiting makes your application frozen and Windows may offer to kill it if it stays unresponsive for too long.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on API exposed by that dll. If they provide synchronous API then you do not need any pause at all. Your thread will enter dll code and when it returns back to your code result will be there.

However if API is async there should be either poll methods or callbacks.

Anyway if you provided code of API I would be able to give more relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

A thread join may do the trick if the dll code in question is asynchronous. Is there anyway you can gain access to the underlying thread being used to read the serial port?

Answer (score 0):

If the API is synchronous, call the API in another thread.  When you start that thread, disabled all the relevant controls in your UI (or disable the whole form; but that's not usually a good user experience) and provide some sort of notification (e.g. text on a status bar).  When the API returns notify the UI that the thread is complete and re-enable the controls and provide some notification to the user.

If the API is asynchronous, disable the controls, provide status, and invoke the API.  When the API notifies you that it has completed (or failed) re-enable the controls and provide status.